# FSR function of the component-wise product, sum, of two LFSR sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, finite-fields, cryptography, coding-theory

Let $T_1$, $T_2$ be two $m$-sequences over $\mathbb{F}_q$ of length $q^n-1$, say $T_1 = (\text{Tr}_{q^n | q}(\alpha^i))_{i \geq 0}$, $T_2 = (\text{Tr}_{q^n | q}(\beta^i))_{i \geq 0}$, for some primitive elements $\alpha, \beta$ of $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$. Let $f_1(x_0,\ldots, x_{n-1})$, $f_2(x_0,\ldots, x_{n-1})$ be the FSR functions of $T_1, T_2$, respectively.

**Question:** What are the FSR functions of the sequences $T_1 \cdot T_2$, $T_1 + T_2$, where the $\cdot, +$, mean component-wise multiplication, addition, of the sequences. Can we write these FSRs in terms of $f_1, f_2$? Are these NLFSRs? My apologies if these questions are trivial; they are not mentioned in my book. Thanks!

Comment: $T_1+T_2$ is the easy one; its feedback shift register _polynomial_ is the product of the feedback shift register _polynomials_ of $T_1$ and $T_2$.  $T_1\cdot T_2$ is the harder one. I would suspect that the answer can be found in a paper dealing with _generalized Reed-Muller codes_ dating back published in the mid-1970s. The authors were Delsarte, Goethals, and MacWilliams if I recall correctly.

Comment: It's not entirely clear (to me) what kind of non-linear feedback functions you would allow. If we restrict ourselves to LFSRs, then IIRC the linear complexity of the sequence gives the answer. The linear complexity of the sequence $T_1+T_2$ is, as Dilip pointed out, equal to $2n$ except in the degenerate case when the two sequences are identical (or $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are Frobenius conjugates of each other). In the case of $T_1\cdot T_2$ the linear complexity is bounded from above by the cardinality of the set $$S=\{\alpha^{q^i}\beta^{q^j}\mid 0\le i,j<n\}.$$

Comment: So if we restrict ourselves to LFSRs we never need registers longer than $2n$ and $n^2$ respectively, and the latter bound can be improved to $|S|$. If you allow non-linear feedback functions, then I don't know much. Anyway, the point I wanted to bring up is that these sequence can be generated using a LFSR, but the game is about the length of the register.

Comment: Thanks. I was more or less aware that the characteristic polynomial of the sequences $T_1 + T_2$ and $T_1 \cdot T_2$ is the composed sum, multiplication, of the characteristic polynomials of $T_1, T_2$, respectively. If I recall correctly this is due to Selmer in the 1960s. Now I think the square-free part of the characteristic gives the minimal polynomial. In any case we have an LFSR for the sequence. But it still seems to me a little odd that we can't give an NLFSR for a seemingly simple way of getting non-linearity, like multiplying two LFSRs, etc.

Comment: Non-linearity in shift registers gives me a headache immediately. I don't recall having seen much work done there, but I haven't really paid attention either. The only thing that rings a bell is a talk in the 90s by J.J.Rushanan (from MITRE corporation), who studied the use of quadratic terms in feedback functions. I don't think he had many general results. He did study things like when you still get maximum period sequences, and collected a lot of data on the affect of a few quadratic terms on the linear complexity.

Comment: Looking at it from a slightly different point of view, it isn't at all clear to me how long a snippet of history of the sequence $T_1\cdot T_2$ is needed to determine its future (this number is obviously a lower bound to the length of the shift register generating it). Even in the case $q=2$ I don't know the answer to the "simple" question of the maximal length of a run of  zeros in the product sequence $T_1\cdot T_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's known to the best of my knowledge. If one multiplies two nonzero sequences of periods $T_i$, $i=1,2$ over the same field, one obtains a sequence with period in the interval $$\left[\frac{T_1 T_2}{gcd(T_1,T_2)},T_1 T_2\right].$$

If two $m-$sequences over $GF(q)$ whose minimal polynomials have relatively prime degrees $d_i$ are multiplied then we get the lower bound on the period given by $$(q^{d_1}-1)(q^{d_2}-1)/(q-1)^2.$$

In general, we need to go to the splitting field, where we need to consider all products of the form $\alpha_i \beta_j$ as possible roots of the new minimal polynomial for the product sequence, if the $\alpha_i$ are roots for the first $m-$sequence and $\beta_j$ are for the second. Sometimes, we may end up getting the all zero sequence, and such cases must be avoided.

However, more is known, and not just for m-sequences. Obviously, repeated roots and non irreducible polynomials cause some difficulties, and Hasse derivatives are utilized in some of the work. A few references:

Products of linear recurring sequences, Neal Zierler, W.H Mills
Journal of Algebra 10/1973; 27(1-27):147-157.

A general lower bound for the linear complexity of the product of shift-register sequences, Rainer Göttfert, Harald Niederreiter, Advances in Cryptology — EUROCRYPT'94, Lecture Notes in Computer Science Volume 950, 1995, pp 223-229.

Sequences of Period 2^N –2, Rainer Göttfert, Sequences and Their Applications – SETA 2006, Lecture Notes in Computer Science Volume 4086, 2006, pp 223-236